# Job scheduling for data scraping on Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, scheduler

I'm scraping (extracting) data from a certain website. The data contains two values that I need, namely **(grid) frequency value** and **time**.

The data on the website is being updated every second. I'd like to continuously save these values (append them) into a list or a tuple using python. To do that I tried using *schedule* library. The following job schedule commands run the data scraping function (socket_freq) every second.

```
import schedule
schedule.every(1).seconds.do(socket_freq)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
```

I'm facing two problems:

1. I don't know how to restrict the schedule to run during a chosen time interval. For example, i'd like to run it for 5 or 10 minutes. how do I define that? I mean how to I tell the schedule to stop after a certain time.
2. if I run this code and stop it after few seconds (using break), then I often get multiple entries, for example here is one result, where the first list[ ] in the tuple refers to the time value and the second list[ ] is the values of frequency:

out:

```
(['19:27:02','19:27:02','19:27:02','19:27:03','19:27:03','19:27:03','19:27:03','19:27:03','19:27:03','19:27:03','19:27:04','19:27:04','19:27:04', ...], 
['50.020','50.020','50.020','50.018','50.018','50.018','50.018','50.018','50.018','50.018','50.017','50.017','50.017'...])
```

As you can see, the time variable is entered (appended) multiple times, although I used a schedule that runs every 1 second. What i'd actually would expect to retrieve is:

out:

```
(['19:27:02','19:27:03','19:27:04'],['50.020','50.018','50.017'])
```

Does anybody know how to solve these problems?

Thanks!

(I'm using python 2.7.9)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so here's how I would tackle these problems:

1. Try to obtain a timestamp at the start of your program and then simply check if it has been working long enough each time you execute piece of code you are scheduling.
2. Use [time.sleep()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html?highlight=time.sleep#time.sleep) to put your program to sleep for a period of time.

Check my example below:

```
import schedule
import datetime
import time

# Obtain current time
start = datetime.datetime.now()

# Simple callable for example
class DummyClock:
  def __call__(self):
    print datetime.datetime.now()

schedule.every(1).seconds.do(DummyClock())

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    # 5 minutes == 300 seconds
    if (datetime.datetime.now() - start).seconds >= 300:
        break
    # And here we halt execution for a second
    time.sleep(1)
```

All refactoring is welcome